# Cannot find module 'angularx-flatpickr'

Tags: angular6

i am having the **following** **error** while running my angular app

> Error during template compile of 'SharedModule'
>     Could not resolve angularx-flatpickr relative to "my file path"(16,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angularx-flatpickr'.

Comment: Hi i will be very happy to help you can you please provide the code on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Please provide the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try by removing `package-lock.json`
2. Re-install `npm i angularx-flatpickr`

Comment: Also for me works: 
npm install --save flatpickr angularx-flatpickr

Answer (score 0):

When updating from angular v13-v14 I got that exact message...

For me to resolve:

1. Firstly upgrade angularx-flatpickr to latest (v7.0.0 at the time) as
   is required for ng14+.
2. Update your paths...

Before:

```
import { FlatPickrOutputOptions } from 'angularx-flatpickr/flatpickr.directive';
```

After upgrade:

```
import { FlatPickrOutputOptions } from 'angularx-flatpickr/lib/flatpickr.directive';
```